# Clone deployed Rails application from Heroku to my computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have logged in to my account using `heroku login`. I wonder how I can clone my deployed application from heroku into my computer.
I have not pushed the application into any online git repos like GitHub.

Comment: $ heroku git:clone -a your_app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy git url from your heroku app settings page and do `$ git clone paste-copied-git-url-here`

for example

```
$ git clone git@heroku.com:your-heroku-app-name.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [official documentation here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> To clone the source of an existing application from Heroku using Git, use the heroku git:clone command:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

--

If you're not using `herou toolbelt`, you'll have to authenticate your connection before trying to run any `git` commands. Since you're using `heroku login` etc, the above should be sufficient for you.